# email templates made with MJML which is not rendering correctly in outlook

Tags: html, email, html-email, mjml

I need help in rendering the email templates correctly in outlook. I have used mjml to develop them but for some reason the templates look terrible in outlook only.

Comment: You need some basic info like a minimum reproducible code sample, and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Hi @Nathan, Actually I was able to almost complete the templates in MJML. Now the only problem is that one of the sections is wider than the other sections. Currently it looks like this
https://i.imgur.com/eo5DEJR.png

Comment: AGain, we can't see your code. And don't post an image of your code. Please do look up how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: StackOverflow gives answers. Good answers. A lot of the MJML community hangs out on the Slack MJML channel, including the team managing changes. Answers are usually quick. Friendly crowd.

https://mjml.slack.com/